# google SMTP settings stopped working after 'less secure apps' option is disabled by google

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, gmail

I have a working code for sending emails from my application. This was on production and working good.
Sometime in the last 2 weeks, google disabled the "Less Secure Apps" option. The emails were not going through since then.
Is there any workaround for this?

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email.com", "password");
        SmtpServer.Port = 587; //587
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two work arounds.

## Apps Password

The first involves using an apps password in place of the users password to their google account.  This option requires that you have 2fa enabled though in order to create the [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).

```
 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        client.Authenticate(message.From, "AppsPassword");
        client.Send(message.GetMessage());
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
```

## XOauth2.

The second option involves using xOauth2 authorize the request rather then using a password.

This code requires that you create [installed app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ) credentials.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;

var to = "test@Gmail.com";
var from = "test@gmail.com";

var path = @"C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json";
var scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" };


var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(path).Secrets,
    scopes,
    "GmalSmtpUser",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), true)).Result;



var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    From = from,
    To = to,
    MessageText = "This is a test message using https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol",
    Subject = "Testing GmailSMTP with XOauth2"
};

try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        
        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (message.From, credential.Token.AccessToken);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2, CancellationToken.None);
        
        client.Send(message.GetMessage());
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


public class EmailMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }

    public MimeMessage GetMessage()
    {
        var body = MessageText;
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("From a user", From));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("To a user", To));
        message.Subject = Subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };
        return message;
    }
}
```

The refresh token will expire after seven days until you set the project to production in the oauth2 consent screen.

Answer (score 0):

Note: We need to enable 2-factor authentication in google account before proceeding.

Less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) options is deprecated.

We can use apppasswords which even more convenient. Here is the link:
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords

Use 16 digit code provided by google instead and that will serve as password.

[image]